# VB.NET Selection of item by key inside collection: Try ... Catch vs. For Each

Tags: vb.net, collections

I'm just wondering what would be the best programming technique for selecting an item inside of a collection by string (or key). To cut the story short, here the two sample codes:

Code (1): Try ... Catch

```vb
Sub TryCatchExample()
  ' Define the objects ...
  Dim col_List As Collection
  Dim label_Item As Windows.Forms.Label
  Dim object_Result As Object

  ' Assign something to the collection ...
  label_Item = New Windows.Forms.Label
  label_Item.Name = "Label_1"
  col_List.Add(label_Item, label_Item.Name)

  ' Now try to find "Label_2" by using Item property with key string ...
  Try
      object_Result = col_List.Item("Label_2")
      ' Do something if available ...
  Catch ex As Exception
      ' We can look up for the reason of error, 
      ' but for this example we will skip this.
      ' Couldn't find "Label_2" ...
      Debug.Print("Couldn't find your requested object by string: 'Label_2'")
  End Try
End Sub
```

Code (2): For ... Each

```vb
Sub ForEachExample()
  ' Define the objects ...
  Dim col_List As Collection
  Dim label_Item As Windows.Forms.Label
  Dim object_Result As Object

  ' Assign something to the collection ...
  label_Item = New Windows.Forms.Label
  label_Item.Name = "Label_1"
  col_List.Add(label_Item, label_Item.Name)

  ' Now try to find "Label_2" by browsing through collection ...
  For Each object_Item As Object In col_List
      If object_Item.Name = "Label_2" Then
          object_Result = object_Item
      End If
  Next

  ' Now we have to check if there is an object available ...
  If object_Item Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print("Couldn't find your requested object by string: 'Label_2'")
  End If
End Sub
```

For code (1) we have to run into an error to discover that "Label_2" key isn't available. For code (2) we have to write some more lines, but it will do the same.

Now the question: *What's the better way to do?*

Comment: Obviously code n.1 more compact, more readable and also should be faster since the collection should be implemented as a hash table. Setting up exception handling has some overhead, sure, but I still prefer it.

Comment: @A.S.H Horrible advice. The first option is bad.

Comment: @varocarbas in most situations, one may be sure of the existence of the key in the collection, and could use option 1 without even exception handling. Even if not sure, better to search in a hash table (O(1)) than iterating all items (O(n))

Comment: @A.S.H The OP algorithm is wrong, there is no need to iterate through all the elements. Note that the functions in charge of looking for a given key (e.g., Contains) are actually built on loops; they are optimised versions with much better readability than loops but not something much better. Try Catch shouldn't ever be considered. Either improve the loop (e.g., exit when finding the key) or rely on a different approach (as suggested in my answer: LINQ) or make sure that the given class accepts certain approaches (e.g., Contains or IndexOf..). There are many options, but not Try Catch.

Comment: I agree there are better methods, but actually i was not giving a "best solution", but comparing iteration to search by key. I must say that it is  somehow a troublesome design choice that the collection raises an exception in case the key is not found, but it is like that...

Comment: One question: why are you using Collection? Why not a list or an array or an arralist or a dictionary or any of the multiple .NET alternatives bringing lots of flexibily? You cannot even use LINQ with a Collection! In that case, just rely on the loop by breaking it inside the condition. But you should better rely on different type.

Comment: @A.S.H Actually I deleted my answer because with Collection you cannot do anything (not even rely on LINQ). Anyway... the try catch is not an option. If the OP wants to rely on a Collection (not sure why), might use the loop and exit it inside the condition. It will be quick enough (try catch is not only a bad algorithm approach, but also a performance-killer).

Comment: Yeah, usually time is not critical when working with GUI... So I'd say to the OP use whatever suits your taste...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ varocarbas: You're correct, the loop should be exited when the requested object is found. So for code (2) it should be added at the if-clause: 'Exit For'. Also there are better ways to handle lists of objects, as you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the link of *Hans Passant* to MSDN for methode *Contains()* of Collection object (as always: read the f____ manual), here an answer to my question.

At first for code (2) the user *varocarbas* found a fundamental missing item: Exit For.

```vb
For Each object_Item As Object In col_List
  If object_Item.Name = "Label_2" Then
      object_Result = object_Item
      ' Just to avoid browsing through all elements ...
      Exit For
  End If
Next
```

The following solution might be a good technique to find the right element without using Try ... Catch and For Next.

Link: [MSDN article 'Collection.Contains()'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Code (3a) Contains Methode

```vb
Sub ContainsExample()
    ' Define the objects ...
    Dim col_List As Collection
    Dim label_Item As Windows.Forms.Label
    Dim object_Result As Object

    ' Assign something to the collection ...
    label_Item = New Windows.Forms.Label
    label_Item.Name = "Label_1"
    col_List.Add(label_Item, label_Item.Name)

    ' Now try to find "Label_2" by Contains method of collection ...
    If col_List.Contains("Label_2") Then object_Result = col_List.Item("Label_2")
    If object_Result Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Do the stuff with the result ...
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Code (3b) Contains Methode

```vb
Sub ContainsExample()
    ' Define the objects ...
    Dim col_List As Collection
    Dim label_Item As Windows.Forms.Label
    Dim object_Result As Object

    ' Assign something to the collection ...
    label_Item = New Windows.Forms.Label
    label_Item.Name = "Label_1"
    col_List.Add(label_Item, label_Item.Name)

    ' Now try to find "Label_2" by browsing Contains() method of collection ...
    If col_List.Contains("Label_2") Then 
        object_Result = col_List.Item("Label_2")
        ' Do the stuff with the result ...
        ' ...
    Else
        Debug.Print("Couldn't find the requested object by string: 'Label_2'")
    End If 
End Sub
```

Finally to say there might be better solutions with other list/array objects as mentioned in the comments.